# Android: Implement azimuth orientation sliding view

Tags: android, compass-geolocation, android-view, azimuth, android-orientation

I am trying to create a ruler view based on azimuth compass orientation value. The idea is to place a small view at the bottom of a camera view which slides to the left or to the right according to the azimuth value obtained from the "orientation" sensor.

Something like this:

[image]

My main conceptual problem is to understand how I can wrap up the bar if I keep rotating the phone in the same direction. I am looking for ideas on how to solve this problem! Can this problem be solved with Bitmaps?

Which classes/tools are suitable for this? Are there any examples on how to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Did u find anything to do this??